# How to remove the duplicate tab when we adding tab in run time

Tags: android, android-tabhost, android-tabs

I created tab dynamically in onClick of listview. Whenever I click the same list item the duplicate tab is opening for the same list item.How can I prevent the duplicate tab opening in onClick of list item

Here is my Code

```
 protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, final int position, long id) 
 {

    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);  
    TabHost tabHost = Tabviewactivity.self.getTabHost();
    FriendInfo friend = friendAdapter.getItem(position);
    Intent i = new Intent();
    i.setClass(this, Messaging.class);
    i.putExtra(FriendInfo.USERNAME, friend.userName);

    String friend_name = friend.userName;
    tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec(friend_name +  Integer.toString(z)).
                           setIndicator(friend_name).setContent(i));
    tabHost.setCurrentTab(z);
    z++;

 }
```

Thanks

```
    TabHost tabHost = AllFriendList.self.getTabHost();
    int position = tabHost.getCurrentTab();

Log.d("Position",Integer.toString(position));
Log.d("Z val in delete()",Integer.toString(z));
if(position >0)
{
tabHost.getCurrentTabView().setVisibility(View.GONE);
tabHost.setCurrentTab(position+1);
z-=1;
if(z<0)
z=0;
}
else if(position == 0)
{
tabHost.getCurrentTabView().setVisibility(View.GONE);
tabHost.setCurrentTab(position+1);
z=0;
}
else if(position == z)
{
tabHost.getCurrentTabView().setVisibility(View.GONE);
tabHost.setCurrentTab(z-1);
Log.d("Z value in final","lol");
Log.d("Pos",Integer.toString(position));
Log.d("z pos",Integer.toString(z));
}
TabActivity parent = (TabActivity) getParent();
TabHost tabhost = parent.getTabHost();
tabhost.setCurrentTab(z+1);
for(int i=0;i<tabList1.size();i++)
{
if(tabList1.contains(frnd_position1))
{
tabList1.remove(i);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the clicked position in an `ArrayList` after creating the Tab and in the click check if the selected position is already present in the ArrayList or not..if present do not add a tab else add a new tab..

```
ArrayList<Integer> tabList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, final int position, long id) {

super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id); 

if(!tabList.contains(position)) {
 TabHost tabHost = Tabviewactivity.self.getTabHost();

 FriendInfo friend = friendAdapter.getItem(position);
 Intent i = new Intent();
 i.setClass(this, Messaging.class);
 i.putExtra(FriendInfo.USERNAME, friend.userName);

 String friend_name = friend.userName;
 tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec(friend_name + Integer.toString(z)).setIndicator(friend_name).setContent(i));
 tabHost.setCurrentTab(z);
 z++;

 tabList.add(position);
}
}
```

Comment: one more help @bakriOnFire is possible to set the tab which is already open when i click the list item second time

Comment: u can use tabHost.setCurrentTabByTag(tag) in the else condition using the tag that u've set while creating newTabSpec..

Comment: thank u for your reply. i have one more problem, if i close the tab i cant able to open the tab again. for that i write a code delete the array list in closeTab() so now i can able to open the duplicate tab.can u give any solution for this?

Comment: didn't get u..what u r doing is correct...why it is'nt working?

Comment: the problem is i am deleting the tab in child activity but adding array list from another child activity. i have added my closeTab() above